# python confusion on importing modules

Tags: python-3.x

I saw this statement

```
from django import forms
```

the folder structure is

```
django\
  __init__.py
  forms\
     __init__.py
     ..(continues)
```

My doubt is instead of the above statement why cant we imports forms like this.

```
import django.forms
```

> when i tried this in pycharm. it says unused import statement.

the following is my code:

```
#from django import forms

import django.forms 

    from .models import Post

    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

it gives me error

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
NameError: name 'forms' is not defined
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're asking "why can't you do that"? I'm pretty sure you can, you just get a slightly less compact name out of it (you need to use `django.forms.whatever` instead of `forms.whatever`). Have you tried it and got an error?

Comment: _why cant we import_ we can.

Comment: I tried in pycharm it says it says unused import statement. edited my question

Comment: Well, are you using `django.forms` after importing it? If not, then the message is correct. If you simply haven't written the code that will use the package you've imported, then just ignore the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages),

> ... when using syntax like import item.subitem.subsubitem, each item
>   except for the last must be a package; the last item can be a module
>   or a package but can’t be a class or function or variable defined in
>   the previous item.

Then since its `__init__.py` designates `forms` as a package, you should be able to import it via `import django.forms`. Accessing its members will be different since where before you wrote `forms.x` now you would write `django.forms.x`.

Comment: I am guessing `unused import statement` is only a friendly warning. As soon as you actually use something in `django.forms` it should go away. If not, this could be a bug in pycharm.

Comment: added the complete code. See the edited question Because i am using forms it should not show such warning.

Comment: There is a difference in meaning between `import y from x` and `import x.y`. In the latter case you need to write the full name `x.y` whenever you use it. So your code should work correctly if you change `forms.ModelForm` to `django.forms.ModelForm`.